# Regular Expression for splitting on slash

Tags: python, sql, regex

I am trying to split URLs to get the domain name.

```
example.com                => example.com
example.com/dir/index.html => example.com
```

The regular expression I am trying to us is

```
(.+?)(/|$)
```

When I use it in python like this:

```
import re
m = re.search('(.+?)(/|$)', url)
```

It works for the first one, but for the second example I always get `example.com/`. How do I get rid of the backslash?

edit: I am very sorry, I forgot to include one important information. I need a regular expression, because I need to write this in Oracle SQL. Fortunately, Oracle supports regex, but nothing like `urlparse`. I am just using python for testing. Sorry about that!

Comment: First, why are you using a regular expression for splitting on slash when `url.split('/')` does that more simply.

Comment: Second, why are you parsing URLs manually instead of using `urllib.parse`?

Comment: I second @abarnert. A re isn't necessary here at all.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. +1 and +1 to both @abamert's comments as well.

Comment: Also, that isn't a URL. Or, rather, it's a relative URL to a directory named "example.com" underneath the current base (e.g., `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010179/example.com/dir/index.html`), which isn't exactly useful.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to do this is to use the [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) function in the stdlib:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> url = 'http://example.com/dir/index.html'
>>> p = urlparse(url)
>>> p.netloc
'example.com'
```

Besides being a whole lot simpler, it handles cases that you haven't thought of in a well-defined and clearly-documented way (e.g., what if there's a port as well as a host?), whereas with your code, who knows what happens with any cases you didn't anticipate?

---

If you really want to treat the URL as a string instead of a URL, the easy way to split on slashes is to split on slashes:

```
>>> bits = url.split('/')
>>> bits[2]
example.com
```

---

If you really want to use regexps to split on slashes, you could use `re.split` instead of trying to figure out a way to trick `re.search` into splitting for you:

```
>>> bits = re.split('/', url)
>>> bits[2]
example.com
```

---

Finally, if you want to do it with `match` or `search`, and you don't want to capture the `/`, don't put the `/` in a capturing group, and look at the group you went out of your way to capture instead of at the whole string:

```
>>> url = 'example.com/dir/index.html'
>>> m = re.search('(.+?)(/|$)', url)
>>> m.groups()
('example.com', '/')
>>> m = re.search('(.+?)(?:/|$)', url)
>>> m.groups()
('example.com',)
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the detailed answer!
I edited my original question, because I forgot something. I tryed using the regex you suggested and when I use `m.groups()` it works like expected. But if I use `m.group()` or if I try it in my Oracle SQL using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` I still get `example.com/` Why is that and how can I avoid it?

Comment: @Foaly: Just… don't use `m.group()`. Use `m.group(1)` to match the first group, or `m.groups()` to match all the groups. I don't understand why you're creating separate groups in your regexp just to ignore them and use `group()`, but there is no way you can intentionally ignore the separate groups and yet still get the results of those separate groups. It's like saying "I tried to paint my house red by buying red paint, throwing it in the trash, and painting everything green. How do I make it red?"

Comment: @Foaly: More importantly, why are you using regexps in the first place? If you don't think the simpler and better mechanisms can accomplish what you want, try to explain what you want to accomplish and we can tell you otherwise. See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for more explanation.

Comment: Yes I think this is the case here! Sorry for waisting everybody's time. I will rethink my problem and ask a new question. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Foaly: No problem. Sometimes you have to ask the wrong question to find out the right question. (Or at least sometimes _I_ do, so I certainly don't expect more out of others than myself.)

Answer (score 0):

Try matching for non-froward slash, like `([^/]+?)(/|$)`